# Сортировка объектов в Python

Tags: python

Допустим, у меня есть куча футболок, которые мне нужно рассортировать по цвету.
Все "футболки" хранятся в списке **tshirts_lst** в виде строк формата `'id;color;material'`. Например: `'001;white;cotton'`

Если допустить, что цветов всего 3 (white, black, gray), то рассортировать "футболки" по цвету можно циклом и иф-елсе:

```
white_tshirt = []
black_tshirt = []
gray_tshirt = []

for t_shirt in tshirts_lst:
    if 'white' in t_shirt:
        white_tshirt.append(t_shirt)
    elif 'black' in t_shirt:
        black_tshirt.append(t_shirt)
    elif 'gray' in t_shirt:
        gray_tshirt.append(t_shirt)
```

*(да, корректней было бы искать "цвет" более явно в сплитованных строках, но в данном случае это не суть)*

Но... если мне каждый из "цветов" нужно рассортировать еще и по "материалу" - создавать еще девять списков и делать еще три цикла по три иф-елсе? А если заранее неизвестно количество и названия "цветов" и "материалов"?

Есть более изящное и масштабируемое решение подобной сортировки? Может, через классы или есть способ создавать новые списки/условия динамически?

Подскажите, плиз, в какую сторону гуглить, или может кто видел подобные решения.
Заранее спасибо.

**UPD:**
Возможно, я не совсем корректно использовал слова "сортировка", и правильней было бы написать "рассортировка".
В общем, на выходе все одинаковые "футболки" должны быть в своем отдельном списке: список "белых хлопковых", список "черных хлопковых", список "белых синтетических" и т.д. Количество списков на выходе равно количество цветов умноженное на количество материалов.

Проблема в том, что количество цветов/материалов и их вариаций не всегда постоянное и может расширяться в будущем, поэтому просто городить стационарную конструкцию из циклов и иф-елсе (пусть и завернутые в функцию) не вариант - нужно что-то масштабируемое.

Comment: `sorted(tshirts_lst, key=lambda s: s.split()[1])`.

Answer (score 3):

Это не сортировка, а распределение (по корзинам по ключу). Ключ - кортеж цвет-материал. Функция `distribute` принимает список и функцию-ключ, возвращает список корзин. Каждая корзина хранит все элементы списка с одинаковым ключом:

```
def distribute(lst, key):
    d = {}
    for item in lst:
        d.setdefault(key(item), []).append(item)
    return list(d.values())


tshirts_lst = [
    '001;white;cotton', '002;white;poliestr', '003;black;cotton',
    '004;white;poliestr', '005;black;cotton', '006;black;poliestr',
    '007;gray;cotton', '008;gray;cotton'
]


def key(s):
    return tuple(s.split(';')[1:])


print(*distribute(tshirts_lst, key), sep='\n')
```

> ```
> $ python distribute.py
> ['001;white;cotton']
> ['002;white;poliestr', '004;white;poliestr']
> ['003;black;cotton', '005;black;cotton']
> ['006;black;poliestr']
> ['007;gray;cotton', '008;gray;cotton']
> ```

P.S. Как вы функцию `key` напишите, так `distribute` и будет распределять элементы. Ограничение языка - `key` должен возвращать кортежи, не списки.

Comment: Спасибо за еще более лаконичную версию такого, как Вы правильно выразились, распределения.

Answer (score 2):

Преобразовать список в `pandas.Dataframe` и сортировать/группировать как угодно по каким угодно полям.

Так как в задании был апдейт, у меня в ответе тоже апдейт.
Сначала код для сортировки (в смысле алгоритмического понятия "сортировка") одного списка по значениям:

```
import pandas as pd

t_shirts_lst = ['001;white;cotton',
                '002;red;cotton',
                '003;green;cotton',
                '004;white;wool',
                '005;white;cotton',
                '006;red;wool',
                '007;white;cotton',
                '008;red;acrylic',
                '009;green;cotton',
                '010;white;wool',
                '011;white;linen',
                '012;red;wool'
                ]

t_shirts_df = pd.DataFrame(
    [a.split(';') for a in t_shirts_lst],
    columns=['id', 'color', 'material']
)

#можно сортировать любое количество столбцов
#с любым количеством значений в любом порядке
t_shirts_df.sort_values(
    by=['color', 'material'],
    inplace=True,
    ascending=[False, True],
    ignore_index=True
)

print(t_shirts_df)
```

Результат:

```
|    | id  | color  | material  |
| -- | --- | ------ | --------- |
|0   |001  |white   |cotton     |
|1   |005  |white   |cotton     |
|2   |007  |white   |cotton     |
|3   |011  |white   |linen      |
|4   |004  |white   |wool       |
|5   |010  |white   |wool       |
|6   |008  |red     |acrylic    |
|7   |002  |red     |cotton     |
|8   |006  |red     |wool       |
|9   |012  |red     |wool       |
|10  |003  |green   |cotton     |
|11  |009  |green   |cotton     |
```

Если нужно вернуть обратно в список:

```
t_shirts_lst = [a[0]+';'+a[1]+';'+a[2] for a in t_shirts_df.values.tolist()]
```

Ниже код для сортировки (в смысле "сортировка вещей по кучкам"). В результате получаем список списков с "разобранными вещами":

```
import pandas as pd

t_shirts_lst = ['001;white;cotton',
                '002;red;cotton',
                '003;green;cotton',
                '004;white;wool',
                '005;white;cotton',
                '006;red;wool',
                '007;white;cotton',
                '008;red;acrylic',
                '009;green;cotton',
                '010;white;wool',
                '011;white;linen',
                '012;red;wool'
                ]

#конвертируем список в датафрейм
#сразу разбиваем значения по колонкам
t_shirts_df = pd.DataFrame(
    [a.split(';') for a in t_shirts_lst],
    columns=['id', 'color', 'material']
).set_index('id', drop=True)

#группируем по цветам и материалам
#на выходе имеем словарь, где ключ - кортеж (цвет, материал),
#а значение - список индексов соответствующих вещей
g = t_shirts_df.groupby(['color', 'material']).groups

#превращаем словарь в список списков
t_shirts_lst = [
    [ind + ';' + k[0] + ';' + k[1] for ind in v] 
    for k, v in zip(g.keys(), g.values())
]

print(t_shirts_lst)
```

Comment: @ΝNL993 Виноват, исправился.

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот так сортировать, с предварительным превращением списка в список списков

```
def transform(mas):
    ret = []
    for item in mas:
        ret.append(item.split(';'))
    return ret

listFut = transform(futbols)

sortList = sorted(listFut, key=lambda row: (row[1],row[2]))
for it in sortList:
    print(it)
```

в row[x] указываются номера "полей для сортировки"

Answer (score 1):

Можно предложить такой вариант. (там ещё генератор примера, я его не стал убирать, вдруг пригодится)

```
from itertools import groupby
from random import choice


def color_material(tshirt):
    return tshirt.split(':', 1)[1]


tshirts_lst = ['{:03}:{}:{}'.format(i,
                                    choice(['white', 'black', 'gray']),
                                    choice(['cotton', 'silk', 'wool']))
               for i in range(30)]

tshirts_sorted = sorted(tshirts_lst, key=color_material)
tshirts_grupped = groupby(tshirts_sorted, key=color_material)
for key, tshirts in tshirts_grupped:
    print(list(tshirts))
```

Comment: Может, я некорректно написал условия, но список "футболок" не нужно формировать - он уже есть, их нужно просто рассортировать на все black_silk в одном списке, все white_cotton в другом и т.д.

Comment: ...но спасибо: в целом Ваше решение с задачей справляется, если его чуть подшаманить под мои нужды)

Comment: Вместо функции color_material, я прогнал изначальный список через аналогичную функцию color, а затем полученные из нее отсортированные списки прогнал через аналогичную функцию material

Comment: Ну формирование списка я "нарисовал", потому что было лень набирать пример руками :)   Вроде бы мой "короткий" вариант с общей функцией `color_material`дает от же результат, что  с отдельными функциями, разве нет? Только я не разглядел и двоеточие вместо ; использовал, учтите.

Comment: Двоеточие заметил)) Нет, color_material не совсем то выдает: он складывает футболки по цвету в один список, а внутри его просто сортирует их по материалу. Но в целом классные библиотеки, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Не думал использовать ООП? Создать список объектов футболок и сортировать их, как захочешь?

```
class Tshirt:
    def __init__(self, id, color, material):
       self.id = id
       self.color = color
       self.material = material
```

Comment: Думал, но с ООП еще не сталкивался. Как создать объекты класса понимаю, но как их дальше сортировать - не совсем (

Answer (score 0):

Пока что вот такой рабочий вариант получился на основе предложенных решений.

```
from itertools import groupby

# Исходный список "футболок"
tshirts_lst = ['001;white;cotton', '002;white;poliestr', '003;black;cotton', '004;white;poliestr', '005;black;cotton', '006;black;poliestr', '007;gray;cotton', '008;gray;cotton']

def color(tshirt):
    return tshirt.split(';')[1]

def material(t):
    return t.split(';')[2]


tshirts_sorted = sorted(tshirts_lst, key=color)
tshirts_grupped = groupby(tshirts_sorted, key=color)


sorted_color = []
for key, tshirts in tshirts_grupped:
    sorted_color.append(list(tshirts))


sorted_color_material = []
for t in sorted_color:
    tshirts_sorted = sorted(t, key=material)
    tshirts_grupped = groupby(tshirts_sorted, key=material)
    for key, tshirts in tshirts_grupped:
        sorted_color_material.append(list(tshirts))

for lst in sorted_color_material:
    print(lst)

# На выходе
['003;black;cotton', '005;black;cotton']
['006;black;poliestr']
['007;gray;cotton', '008;gray;cotton']
['001;white;cotton']
['002;white;poliestr', '004;white;poliestr']
```

Думаю, можно решить эту задачу еще более лаконично через классы и объекты, но с ООП пока нет никакого опыта. Буду благодарен, если кто-то подскажет алгоритм действий через классы/объекты.

Comment: Не заморачивайтесь "заранее" с ООП :) особенно в Питоне, если это не является (само)образовательной явно сформулированной задачей. В Питоне классы нужны реже, есть много-много готовых функций и классов для разнообразных задач в стандартной библиотеке и во внешних.